# DNS server is not working - timed out

Tags: windows, domain-name-system, windows-server-2012-r2

I have 2 child controllers. But one of the controller can resolve names and the other doesn't. I can't find out the cause. Any suggestions to troubleshoot this?

Edit: It seems like `AD_child_02` cannot resolve `example.com` but it can resolve `testserver1.example.com`.

`AD_child_01` can resolve `example.com` and it can also resolve `testserver1.example.com`

**AD_child_01 (10.10.10.10) - test1.example.com**

**AD_child_02 (10.10.10.20) - test1.example.com**

When testing with AD_child_01 :

```
nslookup test_server 10.10.10.10
Server:  AD_child_01 
Address:  10.10.10.10

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    test_server
Addresses:  10.10.10.30
```

When testing with AD_child_02 :

```
nslookup test_server 10.10.10.20
Server:  AD_child_02 
Address:  10.10.10.20

DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
*** Request to AD_child_02  timed-out0
```

Comment: DNS Server service on AD_child_02 started? Local nslookup on AD_child_02 works? Netstat on AD_child_02 shows listening port 53? Firewall on AD_child_02 set up correctly for TCP/UDP 53?

Comment: Updated the question. It can resolve x.example.com but it cannot resolve example.com. anything with xx.example.com is the entries that are in AD_child_02. But it should be forwarding or something like to resolve the other address. I'm not sure what's wrong. AD_child_01 works btw. There is no firewall issue or port issue. Everything is open.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out the issue. AD_child_02 forwarder was pointing to old (non existence) domain controller. I updated forwarder  to point to AD_Parent_01 and now it can resolve example.com